# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net

I am not able  to get the actual cause of this error in my Web Application.I am using IIS7.0 and .Net FrameWork 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You have inputted html tags in the input field,

Put validateRequest="false" in your page directive or web.config file.

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972967.aspx

Comment: This only has an effect on ASP.NET WebForms, but not ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You're posting some values that are or resemble HTML. Are you using ASP.NET MVC? If so, I blogged a solution [here](http://www.csharpcity.com/outputting-raw-html-in-razor/): specify the attribute `ValidateInput(false)` on the controller method and everything will work.

But make sure this is the *right* solution. Does your app allow posting of HTML? If so, this is what you need to do; if not, you're just opening a security loophole.

Comment: What if I have a million controller methods? There must be a way that doesn’t require me to go through everything and add a million attributes?

Comment: Timwi, did you see @sudheshna's answer? That seems to be what you want. I had this only on one form method, so I was content with a single attribute, and *not* disabling XSS/etc. protection across my app. Are you sure you know what you're doing?